# iframe not displaying on mobile browser

Tags: php, html, wordpress, iframe, youtube

I have a wordpress website that has a function to add up to 5 youtube iframes on the home page. It works great on the desktop but seems to try and download random objects on the mobile browser that has the same name as the video url and shows no iframes.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Here's a code sample

```
<div class="cols">
    <div class="col1">
        <h2 class="subheader">Videos</h2>
        <div class="col-sect">
            <div class="videoWrapper">
                <iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/5QtxQ4IuRgE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: ALL mobile browsers?

Comment: this will help you. http://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/

Comment: Yea, on all browsers I tested!  chrome and the native android browser.  Thanks raj will give it a look!